# Ether scan failed "too little funds', Contract-reverted, Value Cancelled

Tags: etherscan, failed-transaction

I tried purchasing tokens on uni swap and the status failed due to 'too little received'. Looking at the ethers can it shows reverted and funds cancelled. I never received any funds back. Is there anyway for me to retrieve them?

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0ecb4b1a92a450e77d201e0672ce89fec2334bb78965d94146d1ba7e2984c6bc

Answer (score 1):

If a transaction is reverted (as is the case for your transaction), then all of its actions are reverted. It's like the transaction never took place. Therefore all of the assets moved in the transaction are also returned to their previous owner.

If you don't see the assets in your wallet, your wallet is probably not synchronized properly with the blockchain, or you are misinterpreting something. It's not possible that the assets wouldn't be returned automatically.